# Xcode loads always debugger

Tags: xcode

When I start Xcode and let it make a new project, no matter witch. And click, build and run. It gifs this error

```
The Debugger has exited with status 0.
[Session started at 2010-10-27 11:14:54 +0200.]
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1472) (Wed Jul 21 10:53:12 UTC 2010)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys000
Loading program into debugger…
Program loaded.
run
[Switching to process 589]
Running…
2010-10-27 11:14:54.602 Math[589:a0f] Can't open input server /Library/InputManagers/Inquisitor`
```

The application does start, and doen't crash, but doesn't even load the views in the nib file.
I already installed a newest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're missing a file in your Xcode install. It probably installed the update wrong or something, The only fix I can think of is reinstalling Xcode from the website.